# How to get all answers of questions even if not answer in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, form-submit

I need to get all answers to questions and if the user unanswered a question. set null on a database for a result of this question.

```
<form action="forms/handle-questions.php" method="post">
<?php foreach ($questions $key => $question) : ?>
  <div class="row">
    <?= $question['question'] ?>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check ">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_<?= $question['id'] ?>" 
            value="good">
     <label class="form-check-label"> good</label>
   </div>
   <div class=" form-check ">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_<?= $question['id'] ?>" 
            value="medium">
     <label class="form-check-label" >medium</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check ">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_<?= $question['id'] ?>"
            value="weak">
     <label class="form-check-label">weak</label>
   </div>
   <?php endforeach ?>
   <button type="submit" name="handle_questions">Done</button>
</form>
```

I already get just questions with its answer with id for each question but I need the other answers and set null for it.

```
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $record) {
    if (strpos($key, 'radio_') !== false) {
        $question_id = str_replace('radio_', '', $key);
        // here get the question id and insert in database 
    }
  }
```

I really don't know how the output will be maybe like this

```
Array
 (
   [radio_1] => good
   [radio_2] => medium
   [radio_3] => medium
   [radio_4] => medium
   [radio_5] => null
   [radio_6] => medium 
   [radio_7] => null
   [radio_8] => null
 )
```

Comment: Please provide the desired o/p

Comment: I edited 
do that help you to understand me ?

Comment: Try the answer once and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding a **hidden field** with question id and filtering the form result,
Like this:
**Form**

```
 <form action="forms/handle-questions.php" method="post">
        <?php foreach ($questions as $key => $question) : ?>
            <div class="row">
                <?= $question['question'] ?>
                <input class="form-check-input" type="hidden" name="question_<?= $question['id'] ?>" value="radio_<?= $question['id'] ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-check ">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_<?= $question['id'] ?>"
                       value="good">
                <label class="form-check-label"> good</label>
            </div>
            <div class=" form-check ">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_<?= $question['id'] ?>"
                       value="medium">
                <label class="form-check-label" >medium</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check ">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio_<?= $question['id'] ?>"
                       value="weak">
                <label class="form-check-label">weak</label>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <button type="submit" name="handle_questions">Done</button>
    </form>
```

**Controller**

```
$answerArray = [];
        $formResult = $_POST;
        foreach ($formResult as $key => $record) {
            if (strpos($key, 'question_') !== false) {
                if(isset($formResult[$record])){
                    $answerArray[$record]=$formResult[$record];
                }else{
                    $answerArray[$record]=null;
                }
                // here get the question id and insert in database
            }
        }
$this->dd($_POST,$answerArray);
```

**Output** like this

[image]